# Count Total lines of python code in specified directory and Execute as Shell Script

Tags: shell

How do you count the number of lines of code in a directory and how do you execute it as a shell script in terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo Please, enter file location as a sub-directory
read LOCATION
cd $LOCATION
find . "(" -name "*.py" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

You can execute it in terminal as `sh theScript.sh`

Answer (score 3):

try `find . "(" -name "*.FILE_EXTENSION_HERE" or -name "*.ANOTHER_FILE_EXTENSION_HERE ")" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`